# "Move up, John, and let her sit down." (What's the meaning of 'up'?)

Tags: adverbs, phrasal-verbs

> "Move up, John, and let her sit down."
> https://www.collinsdictionary.com/ko/dictionary/english/move-up

What's the meaning of 'up' in the sentence above?

The speaker presumes that somebody should/would make his or her body move upwards to *move up*? Or, the direction of the movement doesn't matter at all?

In other words, you can use '*move up*' just to mean 'make sth/sb move a bit to somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

"Up" doesn't always mean *upwards*, ie to a higher altitude. We commonly use "up" to mean "forwards", and also to mean "north".

For example, when travelling northwards to a destination, we might say "I'm going **up** to [place]". On a long vehicle such as a bus or train, moving from the back to the front might be described as "I'm moving **up** to the front of the bus".

"Move up" in the context of your example would mean *move further along* the seat. Depending on the layout of the seating, they might also ask them to "move down".

Comment: Can I say "move down" instead of 'move up'?

Comment: @BEBYGONES Yes, it would depend on the layout of the seating and the perspective of the speaker. But they could both be used.

Comment: It is very common in the UK to say 'shove up!' to people sitting in a row (e.g. on a bench) to make space at the end for one or more new people to sit down. There may be an implication that the people already sitting achieve this by moving or shuffling sideways without getting up, pushing ('shoving') the next person along (all except the person at the other end, who is shoved but does not shove anyone).

Comment: sofa, sitting person, asker: a---*(sitting person)----------b  **asker(right side of the sofa: near b)  — in this case, can the asker say 'move down' to ask the sitting person to move nearer b?

Comment: @BEBYGONES - move up, move down, move along, etc are all OK.